# Z - transform of a transfer function

Tags: transformation, laplace-transform, z-transform

I have to apply a z-transformation to my transfer function which looks like this:

$$\frac{K}{s} - \frac{K\cdot T}{T\cdot s}+1$$

I have tried it and this is my result:

$$K \cdot \frac{z}{z-1} - K \cdot \frac{z}{z-e^{-1}}$$

I do not know what the result should look like so I would like to ask you guys to help me with this. Can anyone prove my result? And if it is wrong can you correct me and explain why is my result not correct please? I would like to learn the z - transformation correctly.

EDIT: As Matt says, I am trying to convert my transfer function from s domain to discrete z-domain.

Comment: As it stands your question does not make sense. The transfer function is a continuous function in the complex variable $s$. The Z-transform is applied to *sequences*, so you can't compute the Z-transform of a transfer function. Do you mean the bilinear transform, which converts a transfer function form the $s$-domain to the discrete $z$-domain?

Comment: @MattL. I think you are right. For some reason I learned it wrong and I also asked my question wrong. You are right, I am trying to convert it from s to discrete z-domain

Comment: OK, now you just have to decide which method you want to use. There is the bilinear transform, the impulse invariant transform, the step invariant transform, etc. And your transfer function does not look right (the first and the second terms cancel each other).